# React native + Mobx, @inject decorator throws an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to use mobx with react native and stuck into a problem.

```
@inject('someStore')
@observer
export class SomeComponent extends Component {
   render() {
       ...
   }
}
```

I'm sure I configured properly babel plugins for decorator but `@inject` decorator gives me an exception `"Expected a constructor."`.

[image]

I have no idea why this happen since I had used mobx in this way in an other project. Does anyone had been through this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downgraded the mobx-react version to 5.4.4 and I can confirm that it works.

Try to downgrade mobx-react.

```
yarn add mobx-react@5.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the class as below worked for me

### "mobx": "^5.13.0","mobx-react": "^6.1.3"

```
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

}

export default inject("userStore")(observer(LoginScreen));
```

Answer (score 1):

**"mobx-react": "^6.1.3"** it works for me

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {observer, inject} from 'mobx-react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
class_content
}

export default inject('someStore', 'someStore' /* here you can add as many store files as you need */)(observer(SomeComponent));
```

But don't forget to add **Provider** to your App.js or which is your main file